# Скрипт на python/django не справляется с большим количеством HTTP запросов. Ошибка 503

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, api

**Всем привет!**

Я начинающий python/django разработчик с опытом менее полу года.
Взял работу и на этапе тестирования столкнулся с ...

К сути дела:

Сайт python/django (в дальнейшем именую скриптом) размещен на хостинге. View скрипта принимает http запрос от сайта №1, обрабатывает данные и делает ответный http запрос на сайт №1.

Проблема возникла, когда на view скрипта был сделан одновременно 61 запрос со стороны сайта №1. Половина запросов вернулись с ошибкой 503.

Хостер пишет, что проблема в том, что зависают запросы.

Со стороны сайта №1 задержку между запросами не сделать, поскольку это CRM система сторонней фирмы, монолитная штука с большими сроками и притязаниями по доработкам.

Тестировал, делая 6 одновременных запросов - отработало корректно.

В итоге я сейчас в тупике.

С чем конкретно может быть связана проблема?
Какие ошибки я допустил?
Как изменить скрипт, чтобы не было этих "зависаний"? 
Может стоит вообще изменить алгоритм и инструменты реализации, но на что?

Прошу пощадить, если в каких-то формулировках я по джуниорски не точен.

Запрос к view скрипта выглядит вот так:

```
mysite.com/script?meta={"id":"20","trigger": "1"}&products=[{"article":"2222", "price_retail":"200", "price_purchase":"100"}, {"article":"1111", "price_retail":"400", "price_purchase":"100"}]
```

Вот код из view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests, json
import retailcrm
import time


def script(request):
    meta_info = request.GET['meta']
    products_info = request.GET['products']
    meta = json.loads(meta_info)
    products = json.loads(products_info)
    ord_id = meta["id"]

    #создание лог файла
    render_log_file(meta, products)

    #обработка принятого json и формирование переменных для отправки ответа
    message, parameters = get_parameters(meta, products)

    #формирование и отправка ответного http запроса
    api_request(ord_id, parameters)

    return HttpResponse(message)


def get_parameters(meta, products):
    standart_deliv = ['1111']
    non_standart_deliv = ['3921', '8354', '2312', '5192', '1734', '9042', '2589']
    sum_retail_code = ""
    sum_purchase_code = ""
    count_code = ""
    sum_retail_val = 0
    sum_purchase_val = 0
    count_val = 0
    trig_number = meta['trigger']
    trig_letter = ""
    order_id = meta['id']
    message = ""

    if trig_number == "1":
        trig_letter = "f"
    elif trig_number == "2":
        trig_letter = "s"
    else:
        trig_letter = "t"

    #формирование кода и значения полей для записи по api
    for i in range(0, len(products)):
        article = products[i]["article"]
        if article in standart_deliv:
            sum_retail_code = "opdk_stand_" + trig_letter + "summ"
            sum_purchase_code = "opdk_stand_" + trig_letter + "summ_purch"
            count_code = "opdk_stand_" + trig_letter + "count"
            sum_retail_val += int(products[i]['price_retail'])
            sum_purchase_val += int(products[i]['price_purchase'])
            count_val += 1
            message = "Стандартная"
        elif article in non_standart_deliv:
            sum_retail_code = "opdk_nonstand_" + trig_letter + "summ"
            sum_purchase_code = "opdk_nonstand_" + trig_letter + "summ_purch"
            count_code = "opdk_nonstand_" + trig_letter + "count"
            sum_retail_val += int(products[i]['price_retail'])
            sum_purchase_val += int(products[i]['price_purchase'])
            count_val += 1
            message = " Нестандартная"

    parameters = {
        "sum_retail_val": sum_retail_val, "sum_retail_code": sum_retail_code,
        "count_val": count_val, "count_code": count_code,
        "sum_purchase_val": sum_purchase_val, "sum_purchase_code": sum_purchase_code
    }

    message += "Код розничной суммы " + sum_retail_code + "  " + str(sum_retail_val) + " Код количества  " + count_code + " " + str(count_val)
    return message, parameters


def render_log_file(meta, products):
    order_info = ""
    about = f'\nНомер заказа {meta["id"]}. Триггера №{meta["trigger"]}'
    for i in range(0, len(products)):
        order_info += f'\narcticle = {products[i]["article"]}, retail price = {products[i]["price_retail"]}'
        order_info += f' purchase price = {products[i]["price_purchase"]}'
    log_text = about + order_info

    with open('log.txt', 'a') as file:
        cur_time = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        # file.write(f'{text}  {cur_time}\n')
        if log_text:
            file.write(f'\nOperation time {cur_time}\n')
            file.write(f'Operation detail {log_text}\n')


def api_request(order_id, args):
    client = retailcrm.v5('https://caloristika.retailcrm.ru', 'UpKLgSX3j9qu')
    order = {
        'id': order_id,
        'customFields': {
            args["sum_retail_code"]: args["sum_retail_val"],
            args["sum_purchase_code"]: args["sum_purchase_val"],
            args["count_code"]: args["count_val"]
        }
    }
    uid_type = 'id'
    result = client.order_edit(order, uid_type)
    response = result.get_response()
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(f'API request completed\n') if response["success"] \
            else file.write(f'API request failed\n')
```

Comment: Какой WSGI сервер используется в проде (надеюсь, не `python manage.py runserver`)?

Comment: python manage.py runserver использую) Альтернативы не знаю.

Comment: найстройте uwsgi + nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django включает в себя реализацию WSGI протокола, которая запускается командой `manage.py runserver`. Это сервер, годный только для разработки; его нельзя использовать в проде. Для прода в питоне существуют разные серверы, имплементирующие WSGI - посмотри например, статью на Full Stack Python: [WSGI Servers](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html). Наиболее популярные, по моему мнению:

- `gunicorn` ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/gunicorn/), [Django туториал](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/))
- `uWSGI` ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/uWSGI/), [Django туториал](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/))
- `mod_wsgi` ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/), [Django туториал](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/))

Есть другие серверы, имплементирующие WSGI (`twisted`, `cherrypy` и т.д.), но не все из них поддерживают Django из коробки, так что читай документацию к ним. Есть и другие серверы, которые умеют крутить Django проекты, но не имплементируют WSGI, к примеру [`daphne`](https://pypi.org/project/daphne/), но я бы не рекомендовал браться за такую экзотику без должного бэкграунда.

Из личного опыта, Apache + `mod_wsgi` на RHEL 7 и среднем серверном железе без особого твика настроек, с включенным кешированием держит ~700 запросов в секунду, с `uWSGI` картина похуже, но примерно в той же плоскости. С `gunicorn` не работал.

Если интересуют сравнения разных серверов, смотри результаты синтетических бенчмарков; к примеру, сравнение по запросам в секунду (картинка из гугля):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В идеале - напиши свои собственные нагрузочные тесты, которые отражают наиболее вероятные сценарии на проде и погоняй их на разных серверах.

Comment: Спасибо. Проверяю решение.

Comment: Оказалось, что мы хостимся на виртуальном хостинге, на котором apache и некий passenger_wsgi. Т. е. wsgi стоит нестандартный, как я понял. Другой wsgi (gunicorn или mod_wsgi) они в рамках услуги виртуального хостинга ставить не хотят. 

Получается нужно переходить на vps и делать свой конфиг?

Comment: Это, скорее всего, [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/), вебсервер для Ruby on Rails; он тоже поддерживает WSGI протокол. Если проект сконфигурирован толково, достаточно переименовать `wsgi.py`, которую `manage.py startproject` создает по дефолту, в `passenger_wsgi.py` и сервер сам задеплоит твой проект. Дальше - в зависимости от ошибок и настроек хостера. В случае чего, гугли "phusion passenger django setup" и смотри примеры конфигураций.